# send messages between process over NSMachport

Tags: cocoa, ipc

Server:

```
     NSMachPort *serverPort = (NSMachPort *)([[NSMachBootstrapServer sharedInstance] servicePortWithName:@"com.mycomp.checker.myport"]);

    [serverPort setDelegate:[[MachPortMEssageHandler alloc] init]];


    NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    [runloop addPort:serverPort forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [runloop run];
```

Client:

```
    NSString *name = @"com.mycomp.checker.myport";
    NSMachPort *port = (NSMachPort *) [[NSMachBootstrapServer sharedInstance] portForName:name];

    if (port) {

        [port sendBeforeDate:[NSDate date] components:[NSMutableArray array] from:nil reserved:0];
    }
```

Server keeps crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in [runloop run] line. Any advice on right usage of NSMachport class for inter process communication

Answer (score 4):

The delegate of `NSMachPort` is a weak property. There's no particular reason to believe it's a zeroing-weak property, internally. It's a certainty that your `MachPortMEssageHandler` instance is deallocated almost immediately. It's an open question whether the server port object has a dangling pointer to it once it does. Since you're encountering a crash, I suspect it does. You could run with Zombies enabled to verify that.

You need to store a strong reference to the delegate object for the duration.

Comment: Thanks Ken, it worked, next challenge is knowing how to get back the original message sent from client to the server delegate, all I have is a (void *), any ideas ?

Comment: The `void*` is a pointer to a Mach message structure, starting with a `msg_header_t`. If you're not already familiar with Mach messages, then you probably shouldn't be using `NSMachPort`. Just use `NSPort`, `NSPortDelegate`, its `-handlePortMessage:` method, and `NSPortMessage`. Even better, if you don't need low-level messaging, use [Distributed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html).

Comment: ended up using Distributed objects. But XPC with its invalidation handlers looks like the right thing to do for IPC.